# Appropriate copy that is not offensive to the user

Tags: user-expectation, copywriting, ux-writing

We currently have a marketplace that allows our users to claim job postings. Once the user claims the job, they are automatically assigned to it.

Some users are flagged because of previous bad behavior. So when this happens, we have to reach out to the user to remove them from the job. This has been a time-consuming process for us, so how do we mitigate this?

The problem is, in this particular flow of claiming jobs (there are multiple different ways to claim jobs), there is no way to know if they have been flagged until after they've provided their email:

1. User clicks on a link that was shared on social media
2. The link takes them to our page
3. They input their email to claim the job
4. Upon submission, if in the backend we determine they are flagged, we display a message that tells them "they can't book jobs"

But what would be a softened way of communicating this? We also can't display ambiguous "Something went wrong" type of errors as we don't want them to think our system is broken. This would also be bad experience for them as they might attempt several times to no avail.

Comment: Along with the message "they can't book jobs" do you provide a path for dispute/resolution?

Comment: Are the users who are flagged for bad behavior ineligible for *all* jobs, or just certain jobs?

Comment: I like Jos' answer below. What will also help is communicating the blocking to the user when they become blocked (before they apply), and modifying your workflow so that users are not assigned to jobs until their eligibility is confirmed.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles - Yes, they will need to reach out to us either via phone or email which we will include in the messaging.

Comment: @Izquierdo - They will be ineligible  to book ALL jobs.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [an article by Wix](https://wix-ux.com/when-life-gives-you-lemons-write-better-error-messages-46c5223e1a2f) I read a while ago, these are some really good guidelines to follow regarding error messages.

1. **Say what happened (and why)**.
   Make it clear and unambiguous what the problem is, for example: "Unable to claim this job". Or to be a bit bolder, replace "unable" for "denied".
2. **Provide reassurance (if available)**.
   Give the user the feeling that this is not necessarily the end of the road, and that there may be a way around the problem (see point 5)
3. **Be empathetic**.
   Speaks for itself. Remember that the user came across an error, which may not always be their fault. Be nice :)
4. **Help them fix it**.
   If there's a way that the user can fix the problem by themselves, give or suggest the solution.
5. **Always give a way out**.
   If there's no immediate solution you can give the user, still give them a 'way out' so they can continue their flow. You generally don't want your users to be stuck and not know what to do next.

And as an extra point, I would suggest not sacrificing clarity for trying to sound "nice". Be clear in your copy and keep it short, but don't sound like a d*ck.

Visual example:
[image: example]

Comment: Thank you for your response. We might need to not get into much details such as saying, "your email has been flagged" because they could be flagged for a variety of different reasons.

For example, they could be flagged because in the client's eyes, they acted unprofessionally; that can be subjective and it's possible that in their own eyes, they weren't unprofessional at all.

What do you think about keeping it somewhat generic? eg, "You are unable to claim this job. If you think you received this message in error, please contact..."?

Comment: @Bera It really depends on your platform and what the problem actually entails. If all you tell them is that they're unable to claim this job, but you don't tell them why, then it's not much more than just saying "error, contact support" which isn't very helpful. As I mentioned in my answer, don't sacrifice clarity over trying not to offend people. Of course, be nice, but people would rather understand the problem (even if it's negative) than be kept uninformed. In the end, it's up to you to decide what you communicate to the user, just be helpful to them :)